# Convert radar parameters to polygon

Tags: algorithm, radar

I have the following list of parameters for a given radar:

```
Latitude
Longitude
Coverage lateral
Coverage horizontal 
Max Range
Power Emitted
```

I would like to convert these parameters to some type of geometry (polygon?) which would represent the coverage for the radar.

Sorry for my extreme ignorance, but is there an existing algorithm that already does this?  Or am I missing parameters?

Comment: Which GIS software?

Comment: if ArcGIS read https://ams.confex.com/ams/pdfpapers/104269.pdf